# Adverb or Adjective

Tags: adjectives, adverbs

What would be correct: Use an adverb to modify another adjective or simply an adjective in the following sentence?

> The technique generates **unnecessary** large number of classifiers
>
> The technique generates **unnecessarily** large number of classifiers

Comment: "The technique generates an unnecessarily large number of classifiers."

Comment: Thank you @Greg. But is there any reason for this choice?

Comment: I think the reason for Greg's choice is that (1) you want an adverb to modify the adjective "large", so the adjective "unnecessary" isn't the right choice, and (2) "unnecessarly" isn't a word but just a misspelling of "unnecessarily". (If it were up to me, I'd just write "The technique generates too many classifiers.")

Comment: Well, thank you @AndreasBlass. I've corrected the misspelling.